# Dynamic home page after login

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement that when userA logs in I have to show test1.aspx as my home page.
When userB logs in then I have to show test2.aspx. How I have to tackle this scenarios. 
Pls dont tell me like

`if(userA)
{
  response.redirect("abc.aspx");
}`

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083755/simple-login-page-and-dynamically-hiding-controls-based-on-session-variable

Comment: if you don't want `if(userA) { response.redirect("abc.aspx"); }` as answer then you have to explain your question more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what answer you're expecting. You need some mechanism to determine which page to send to the user based on some criteria. Either way, it will end similarly to what you've shown as an example "you don't like". What I've suggest would be to group users and check for that group instead.

For instance:

```
if (user.IsMemberOf("some group")
{
    // perform some steps and redirect
}
```

Answer (score 3):

take your user in dropdown list and put condition like this...hope this is helpful to you.

if (DropDownList1.Text == "Admin")
            {

```
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/adminproduct.aspx");
        }
        else if (DropDownList1.Text == "TechSupport")
        {

            Response.Redirect("~/TechSupport/adminproduct.aspx");
        }
        else if (DropDownList1.Text == "Employee")
        {

            Response.Redirect("~/Employee/adminproduct.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an intranet (not internet) website:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"]
    // Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]
    // Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"]

    string str = this.Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER");
    Console.WriteLine(str);





    switch (str.ToLower()) {
        case "domain1\\username1":
            Response.Redirect("test1.aspx");
            break;
        case "domain1\\username2":
            Response.Redirect("test2.aspx");
            break;
        case "domain2\\username3":
            Response.Redirect("test3.aspx");
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("foo");
    }




}
```

If you have an internet website, you need to use ActiveX, which will limit you to IE on Windows.

Of course, if you have a variable number of users, then you should do it via database:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim str As String = Me.Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
        Response.Redirect(GetUrlForUserName(str))
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetUrlForUserName(strUserName As String) As String
    Dim strURL As String = ""

    Using conn As System.Data.Common.DbConnection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())

        If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

        Using cmd As System.Data.Common.DbCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT URL FROM T_UserURLS WHERE UserName = @YOUR_USER_NAME"
            Dim para As System.Data.Common.DbParameter = cmd.CreateParameter()
            para.ParameterName = "@YOUR_USER_NAME"
            para.Value = strUserName
            para.DbType = DbType.AnsiString
            cmd.Parameters.Add(para)
            strURL = System.Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using

        If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Close()
        End If

    End Using

    Return strURL
End Function



Public Shared Function GetConnectionString() As String
    Dim sb As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    sb.DataSource = Environment.MachineName
    sb.InitialCatalog = "master"

    sb.IntegratedSecurity = True
    If Not sb.IntegratedSecurity Then
        sb.UserID = "YOUR_USER"
        sb.Password = "YOUR_PW"
    End If

    sb.PersistSecurityInfo = False
    sb.Pooling = False
    sb.PacketSize = 4096
    sb.MultipleActiveResultSets = True

    Return sb.ConnectionString
End Function
```